# How to use pipes and filters in psexec?

Tags: powershell, psexec

I want to the fetch the 'Status' of Tomcat service using PsExec and Powershell.  As there are few approvals pending with Windows Security team I am forced to use PsExec

I tried executing the following command using PsExec and it works fine

```
PS C:\> .\PSExec.exe \\10.x.x.x -u DOMAIN\sathish -p mypwd cmd /c "powershell -noninteractive -command Get-Service -Name Tomcat"

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  Tomcat             Apache Tomcat 8.5
```

However, I would like to fetch the status of Tomcat by filtering the output and it failed with the following message

```
PS C:\> .\PSExec.exe \\10.x.x.x -u DOMAIN\sathish -p mypwd cmd /c "powershell -noninteractive -command Get-Service -Name Tomcat | Select -ExpandProerty Status"

'Select' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
cmd exited on 10.165.135.81 with error code 255.
```

How to filter the output so that I can get the status of Tomcat ?

Comment: my guess is to put the powershell command in single-quotes like: `PS C:\> .\PSExec.exe \\10.x.x.x -u DOMAIN\sathish -p mypwd cmd /c "powershell -noninteractive -command 'Get-Service -Name Tomcat | Select -ExpandProperty Status'"`

Comment: And there is probably no need to call "cmd" to call "powershell". Keep it short and simple ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following and it worked

```
C:\> .\PSExec.exe \\10.x.x.x -u DOMAIN\sathish -p mypwd cmd /c 'powershell -noninteractive -command "Get-Service -Name Tomcat | Select -ExpandProperty Status" '
```

Open the cmd with single-quotes and execute powershell commands within double-quotes

Thanks all for the help